# Any idea how to send udp ipv6 packet to cooja simulation

Tags: c, linux, ipv6, contiki, iot

I have done rpl-border-router.c as router on sky mote and 1 udp-server.c mote on sky in cooja. I connect router using tunslip utility.

I can ping my server as well as router.

I want to send udp data to server via my linux as host via tun0, but i cant manage to send on it. I have notice that by ping from terminal it works , by opening in firefox router shows routes, How to send packet to my server via border router from linux as host.

Answer (score 0):

Use netcat!
`netcat -u [node ip] [port]`
this opens up a connection to the UDP server on the node and allows you to send UDP messages from the console.